# How Set background-color To paragraph + justify that

Tags: html, css

I want to set a background color for each line of a paragraph + justify that paragraph.in fact in seems impossible to me and every time i try this it doesn't worked!
This is The code

```css
.paragraph{
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    font-weight: 300;
    /*text-align: justify;*/ /***   This not works when display:inline;    ***/
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #484C55;
    line-height:25px;
    display: inline;
    }
```

```html
<p class="paragraph">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

The problem is When display is inline the text-align:justify doesnt works!
[image: I want to make something like this Picture, Please Help Me !]

Comment: Can you share what you have tried.

Comment: To answer your second question, use `text-align: justify` to justify your text. For it to work,  you need to apply it on a block element (e.g. div, or p).